# MySQL 8.0 Table corrupted

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb, recovery

I was running an optimize on a 70GB+ data table (after adding a bit column), and the database just crashed.
When browsing the data folder, I have a [table].ibd file and a #sql-*.ibd orphan file.

The only way I could restart mysql daemon was to start it with innodb_recovery_mode = 6.
But when reading the table, the columns have values that do not make any since.
One of the columns that is of type BIGINT just repeats the same number for rows on end...

I tried do DISCARD TABLESPACE and the IMPORT it again - it crashes the service while doing it.

InnoDB warns about corrupted table and also corrupted indexes.

I'm looking for help to try and recover the data, since it is very important.
Is it possible to read the .ibd file and recover the data?

I also used "undrop-for-innodb" to try to recover the data, but the values in the rows make no sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to recover from a backup.  You do have a backup ?

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost never necessary.  Next time, don't use it.

Comment: "crash" -- Out of disk space?  Something in the log?  Other clues of which type of "crash"?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (8.0 has some major changes over 5.7.)

Comment: No, unfortunately the backup was deleted, so no backup. yes, most probably the OPTIMIZE TABLE crashed for insufficient disk space.
Running on MySQL version 8.0